# Outpout in R extraction

Tags: regex, r, output

as part of a function R returns

```
[1] Provided that the data is normally: time series estimate = 5478908.4 with confidence interval (4779426,6282453.9)
```

I would just need to get the numbers into a matrix with cols like

```
5478908 4779426 6282453
```

is there a way to do this with the output?

Comment: Or a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

Through negative lookbehind.

```
> x <- 'Provided that the data is normally: time series estimate = 5478908.4 with confidence interval (4779426,6282453.9)'
> regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<!\\d\\.)\\d+", x, perl=T))[[1]]
[1] "5478908" "4779426" "6282453"
```

Comment: or, `strsplit(x, "\\.\\d+|\\D+", perl=T)`, but this will produce empty strings also..

Comment: I don't think OP has `x`. I'm guessing he needs `capture.output`.

Comment: @Davi that is the case yes.....I dont have that how woudl that be possible with capute output?

Comment: ya, just mention capture.output instead of x.. don't work?

Comment: but the studff is outputted by the function...where shall i call capute.output?..how woudl it work in your case?

Comment: how you get the above output you mentioned?